# STL C++11 - Inserters "in place"

Tags: c++11, stl

What are the inserters "in place" of the STL ?

Comment: You probably mean "a family" of [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace) methods?

Answer (score 1):

Normally *in-place* refers to different kinds of algorithms, where *in-place* denotes that the algorithm directly modifies a sequence instead of, as an example, copying the data to later modify it and store it in a new sequence.

```
std::replace      (src.begin (), src.end (), 10, 20);               // (A)
std::replace_copy (src.begin (), src.end (), dst.begin (), 10, 20); // (B)
```

In the above `(A)` replaces elements matching `10` with `20` *in-place*, whereas `(B)` copies the data and write the changes to a new sequence (starting at `dst.begin ()`).

---

It is also worth nothing that the only occurrance of the term *in-place* in the standard is the follow:

> 25.1 **General** `[algorithms.general]`
>
> > <sup>7</sup> Both in-place and copying versions are provided for certain algorithms. When such a version is provided for *algorithm* it is called *algorithm*_copy. Algorithms that take predicates end with the suffix `_if`, which follows the suffix `_copy`.